# Paypal Sandbox notifications are occuring only after the user clicks on the return button

Tags: grails, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been trying to integrate paypal in one of our grails applications. I need to create a monthly subscription wherein automatically payment will be transferred from paypal every month. For the purpose of testing I have created an account in sandbox and created a button for recurring payments. While creating the button I have also mentioned the success url and the cancellation url for IPN. Now while testing the application I see that on the button click the user is redirected to paypal and after logging in the payment also happens successfully. But the notification is not sent as yet. After the payment happens successfully a button appears asking the user whether he would like to return to the application. In case the user clicks on this button then he is redirected to the application else no notification is sent to the user. And also never do I get any notification for the cancellation of a recurring payment. If anyone has faced such a situation before kindly let me know the solution.

Comment: Hi Rammohan, I see that you posted this 3 yrs back. But am having similar situation right now. I am sure you must have found the solution for this and did the IPN configuration on your sandbox account specifying the callback URL as the IPN listener. Can you give the IPN listener configuration and setup code

Comment: Hi Raju, I am sorry but I don't have the code with me anymore. I had done this in my previous company 3 yrs back. Unable to recall the steps either.

Comment: That is ok Rammohan. Thanks you for the prompt response though. I think I will just try to fake the IPN simulator message using a Chrome extension or something.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that you're wondering about the use of CancelURL?

If somebody clicks the cancel link during checkout they will simply be returned to whatever URL you set for this value.  The ReturnURL is where they are sent after completing the subscription setup.

That said, the subscription setup doesn't always guarantee a payment will be made right away.  This could happen at a later time, although it usually does happen pretty much instantly.

If you want to get programmatic notifications of profile payments, or when an actual current profile is canceled, you'll need to use [Instant Payment Notification](https://www.paypal.com/ipn), which will POST all of the transaction data to a script you have sitting on your server so that you can process the data accordingly.

Comment: Can I made recurring payment using `paypal plugin 0.6.8`?